# Get last 12 records from Linq from today date time

Tags: c#, linq

I need last 12 hours record from today date time in linq pls help 
my source code

```
 DateTime? date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-12);
 var records = (from ds1 in caseModelDatabase.DSACommissionViewModel 
         where ds1.LastModifiedDate == DateTime.Now.AddHours(12) select new { }).ToList();
```

in this by last modified date is database record and i have to get the records by last 12 hours who modified.

Comment: `where ds1.LastModifiedDate > DateTime.Now.AddHours(-12)` ?

Comment: Did my answer helped you? Do you need any more assistance?